# Android Resource - An Array to store Country-Name/Country Code

Tags: android, xml

I am storing some informaiton in my android app and per unit of info, I need to store multiple data for each *item* in string-array or what ever appropriate.

For example if we take  a list of countries, the XML file could be defined as follows. Here we have only one value, which is the name of the country that is listed in a **string-array**.

```
<resources>    
<string-array name="countries_array">        
  <item>Bahrain</item>        
  <item>Bangladesh</item>        
  <item>Barbados</item>        
  <item>Belarus</item>        
  <item>Belgium</item>        
  <item>Belize</item>        
  <item>Benin</item>    
</string-array>
</resources>
```

My requirement is to save more info, such as the **country name** and the **country code** in one resource.

My intention is to iterate over a resource and then for each country, I be able to get its sub items such as **country name** and **country code**. This way I can save objects that I need in the application and generate them from parsing the file.

At the moment, I am considering a string split and get the values or by using 2 arrays, but wondering if there is any eligent way to do it. XML and relavent Java code is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<resources>    
<string-array name="countries_array">        
  <item>
    <name>Bahrain</name>
    <code>12345</code>
  </item>
...  
</string-array>
</resources>
```

CountryInfo.java:

```
public class CountryInfo {

    public String mName;
    public String mCode;

    public CountryInfo(String name, String code) {
        mName = name;
        mCode = code;
    }
}

ArrayList<CountryInfo> countryList = new ArrayList<CountryInfo>();
```

Then parse the xml file with an XML parser(SAX or DOM, examples can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)) and then you can add each country info into your array like this:

```
CountryInfo tmp = new CountryInfo(name, code);
countryList.add(tmp);
```